# Trigger a function when clicking an element in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following code creates a simple graph on a powerpoint.

```
Sub test()

    Dim myTextBox As Shape

    'Set element 1
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 15, 10, 20, 30)
        myTextBox.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Set myTextBox1 = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationVertical, 10, 50, 20, 60)
        myTextBox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "JAN"
    End With

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        Set myTextBox = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 40, 20, 20, 20)
        myTextBox.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Set myTextBox1 = .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationVertical, 35, 50, 20, 60)
        myTextBox1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "FEB"
    End With
```

This all works fine. However I want this method to be triggered when somebody is clicking a text element.

So lets say I have an element called "Rechthoek 43". How should I adjust my code so that the test() method is called when clicking "Rechthoek 43"

Comment: VBA has an object model. You could write code to target the object. Is the object a textbox shape?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to select your shape and do:

Insert -> Links -> Action and select Run Macro (Your macro)

Not sure if that is just for action buttons as can't test at present.

Alternative is writing a class to detect the selection of the shape.

Action buttons info:

[Add commands to your presentation with action buttons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-commands-to-your-presentation-with-action-buttons-7db2c0f8-5424-4780-93cb-8ac2b6b5f6ce)

Video demo here of adding an action to an ordinary shape (So seems may be possible)

[Tutorial 2 - Assign Macro to a Shape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xF1bIiYx2mA)

Comment: thanks. I just did it. Its working, however I only get the option to initiate the macro when the file is in presentation modus... Any thoughts on how I can use in normal modus?

Comment: I don't whether that is possible without trying a class. Ppt, i think, needs to be in presentation mode for things like Action links, hyperlinks to work. @steverindsberg is the guru on this https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667023/steve-rindsberg

Comment: @steverindsberg: any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: @QHarr is correct about needing to be in slideshow view for action settings to work (though the guru part is open to debate).  You'll need to set up an event trap, trap selection change events, determine whether the currently selected object is one that should trigger an action.  Google "pptfaq.com events" and "officeone.com events" (w/o the quotes) for info on setting up event traps